# Reliable server-to-iPhone messaging

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

My company offers an iPhone app for day traders which basically tells them when it's a good time to buy or sell. A cluster of servers generate these BUY and SELL signals and need to be delivered to a customer's iOS device in a minute or less. For all other mobile clients we've developed, we are allowed to poll the server in the background (once per minute), to check for updates.

In iOS, however, it seems that doing anything in applicationDidEnterBackground that has to do with times or polling isn't an option.

This led me to look at push notifications, but from what I am reading, they aren't reliable. They employ a send-and-forget methodology, which there's no guarantee they will be received.

You can see the problem with this. If we issue a BUY signal and the user acts on it, then a SELL signal is generated 10 minutes later and send via push, but never arrives, they could lose a lot of money.

So, is there a good way to do this or am I out of luck? Thanks!

Comment: Applications like Colloquy (IRC client) are allowed to keep a TCP connection open for quite a while. Maybe this is an option for you?

Comment: It seems that Colloquy uses APNS as well, can you show me where they claim to have a persistent TCP connection?

Comment: To the person that asked if MMS messages are an option (then deleted the comment?), I am going to have to say no. I don't imagine that MMS or SMS are any more reliable than Push Notifications.

Comment: Not sure they claim it, but when I connect to an IRC server it uses my home connection, not their servers. IRC does not support reconnecting so I would assume that it uses a persistent TCP connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two intermediaries between your server and the user's device: a) Apple and b) the network.

Apple does not guarantee the delivery of all notifications; only the most recent is guaranteed to arrive and only for a limited period of time. For more information, check out the "Quality of Service" section in [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

If the device is accessing the network through a mobile carrier, things may get ugly. I have experienced situations where, some notifications didn't arrive until much later, and some got lost entirely. From my experience, carriers protect -with zeal- the quality of their own services, rather than those of third parties like Apple. An SMS/MMS will not normally be lost, while a push notification might.

Polling the server would be a viable alternative for your app. Alas, Apple doesn't allow networking operations to take place for apps that have been put in the background state (except for Newsstand downloads and VoIP).

Comment: This is what I suspected -- it's really too bad there isn't a better alternative. I hope all allows background processes in the future, but with rules so it can't be abused.

Comment: If you find the 'latest only' to be a limitation, you could keep a list of notifications on the server for the app to check on start.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apple's own push notification service: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

It's quite easy to implement, with just a few lines of code in the application and a bit of PHP and JSON on the server to do the sending. The good thing is that your server sends the request to Apple, and Apple's own servers handle the delivery to the device securely and reliably. Notifications are usually delivered within 10 seconds of being sent (unless the device is offline, then it will be delivered when the device comes online).

From my experience with push notifications, I haven't lost a single one, and there is a delivery option that continuously attempts to deliver it until it is successful, and there is even a server side callback API of some sort available that lets you check the status of your notifications. You could also try a service like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) to do the work for you.

You could also try using one of Apple's [background modes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as part of this (such as receive the 'BUY' as a notification and have the app wait for the 'SELL' in the background. The biggest limitation is that the app can only run in the background for about 10 minutes at a time, so you would have to use a workaround like playing music in the background (or making stock announcements like a music track ;P), or prompting the user to reopen the app to continue the background session.

Comment: I've implemented APNS and since we're sending out quite a few, there are times that a new push notification is sent before the old one gets out and it's overridden. I will check out Urban Airship.

Comment: If you use the backed API, you could make sure the first one got delivered **before** you even send the next one, and keep the next one waiting on your server until the first one arrives. Apple has an obscure API that allows status checking, and urban airship has a slightly less obscure API to do the same thing. The architecture of APNS is very capable and flexible, but also quite obscure, so there aren't many things you **can't** do with it, you just need to find your way around.

Comment: That's good to know! I will check that out. The fact that they don't guarantee anything at all still worries me, but I guess this is the best solution I have available.

Comment: They don't guarantee it because they don't want you to sue them if one notification somehow gets lost. That doesn't necessarily mean it will, it's just safer for Apple. Just make sure you don't guarantee anything like that to **your** users ;)

Comment: Basically, the chance of a device not receiving a notification is about the same as the chance of the device not having an Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps seem to do push notifications really well (GroupMe) while others don't. If you're really worried, you could use a service like Twilio to send the user an SMS message with a link that would open your app and give it some information. So the SMS could say "SELL SELL SELL yourapp://stock=APL" or something like that. This obviously won't work for iPod touch users or iPad users (although I don't know if that will be a problem for you.